# SPFx React JS | Bind a dropdown

Tags: spfx

I have a SPFx React JS web part which populates a grid from SharePoint list. This is working fine. Now, I want to populate a dropdown based on results returned in list. i.e. There is a location dropdown which should populate based on unique values of location returned in result grid.

How can I achieve that please? I wrote a function that would return unique values from result set. But I am not able to call that function in Success() after results are returned. It throws error that function does not exist.

Below is the function :

```
 public getLocations (result) {
var lookup = {};
var items = result;
var resultSet = [];

for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
var name = item.Location.Title;

if (!(name in lookup)) {
  lookup[name] = 1;
  resultSet.push(name);
}
return resultSet;
}

 };
```

But when I try to call this function in Success method, it shows function does not exist.

Comment: did you try something like `this.getLocations(result)` ?

Comment: Yes I did but it only works if I use it in render method using let or Componentdidmount function using let. I am not able to use function that can be called from other multiple functions.

Comment: ok, in your constructor, add the line as `this.getLocations= this.getLocations.bind(this);` and after try calling the function

Comment: Yes I tried that , in that case it shows in console that function is not defined...

Comment: are you fetching the data set in Componentdidmount or a similar method and getLocations() is in the same react component class ??

Comment: I am fetching the data set in Componentdidmount . And in success , I have to bind dropdown with values. Also, getLocations() is in the same react component class.